# Java Spark API 3: How to get a String object from a Column

Tags: java, apache-spark

Can you please tell me how to get a String object from a Column?
There is a Dataset read from the source.
I'm adding a column, and I want to add a value based on one of the String columns.

```java
dataset.withColumn("NEW_COL", myStringFunction(col("SOME_COL));
```

There is a function:

```java
static Column myStringFunction(Column some) {
     String str = ""; // ???? how to get String object
    // ...a few tricky transformations
     return lit(str);
}
```

Comment: myStringFunction should be read together ) there was a break during publication

Comment: Do you mean the column name? or the actual value from a row and query?

Answer (score 0):

The Column class has no method of getting the column name after it's constructed according to [this documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html). You will have to explicitly pass the column name to your method.

```java
dataset.withColumn("NEW_COL", myStringFunction("SOME_COL"));

static Column myStringFunction(String str) {
    // ...a few tricky transformations
     return lit(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[UDFs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-scalar.html#userdefinedfunction) are the way to manage that.

E.g.:

```java
UserDefinedFunction strApp = udf(
  (String s) -> s + " a string", DataTypes.StringType
);
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .config("spark.master", "local[*]")
    .getOrCreate();

spark.sql("select 'I am' SOME_COL").withColumn("NEW_COL", strApp.apply(col("SOME_COL"))).show();
```

yields:

```
+--------+-------------+
|SOME_COL|      NEW_COL|
+--------+-------------+
|    I am|I am a string|
+--------+-------------+
```

per the docs you can also register it for use in text sql functions, but...

If you can it's advised to stick to sql functions (the Spark DSL will do this for you if you wish to stay in java/scala rather than string sqls).  Raw sql (and DSLs) will be faster than any UDF or map function and may benefit from further upgrades in the Spark platform as they are able to be optimised by Spark, your UDF cannot be, it's effectively a black box.

Also please note that whilst "withColumn" is convenient it should not be used to add multiple columns in chains, the performance penalty for this is huge.